# Problem：Why does Wait-Event not wait for an event?

Tags: powershell

Registers the event (BalloonTipClicked) of the NotifyIcon object's click notification, calls its `ShowBalloonTip` Method to pop up the notification, and immediately calls the `Wait-Event`.

When the event has been triggered, the wait is still not finished.

What could be causing this?

Checked the documentation for the relevant Cmdlet and can't find the reason, is there something important I'm overlooking?

The script can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/e9b2949165fae074d3ad6651b762b848

Comment: We need a more complete example of what you're trying, not hosted on an external source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `-Action` method, you can't use the `Wait-Event` method. You can only choose one of these two methods, which is a mistake in my understanding of the documentation.

> This feature provides an alternative to polling for an event. It also
> allows you to determine the response to an event in two different
> ways:
>
> - using the Action parameter of the event subscription
> - waiting for an event to return and then respond with an action

Code after the error has been eliminated ↓
https://gist.github.com/ba504458578dc85b52101a21402bb182

Comment: This is correct.  When Registering the event if you specify an action then the event is handled directly by the action and not sent to the event queue so `Wait-Event` will never see it.  "When you specify an action, events that are raised are not added to the event queue. Instead, the action responds to the event. " https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/register-objectevent?view=powershell-7.1#example-2--specify-an-action-to-respond-to-an-event